# Input language switching keys only accept shift-alt instead of alt-shift

Tags: keyboard, input-language, shortcut-keys

On my Ubuntu UNR install, for some reason, I'm only able to switch the input language if I press <kbd>Shift</kbd> and then <kbd>Alt</kbd>. This is quite the opposite of what usually works -- on Windows and other Ubuntu/other Linux systems -- where I press <kbd>Alt</kbd> and then add <kbd>Shift</kbd>.

Anyone know why this is?

Comment: Try more times for both next source and last source and press shift after 1 seconds that you pressed Alt key. it fixed my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely a papercut.

see https://launchpad.net/hundredpapercuts

Comment: I'll just have to try and file it there.

Answer (score 3):

If it's only happening on your netbook, the issue is probably an incorrect keymap. Low-level tools for examining a keyboard include `xkeycaps` and `showkey`; this should at least tell you what keycodes are getting generated.

At a guess, you may the **Alt** key mapped as **AltGr** or a dead key; in that case the use of **Shift** first might be modifying it back to an **Alt** key. If that was the case however you would typically see this behaviour with only the left or right Alt (I've never seen a keymap with two **AltGr** keys).

Comment: It's weird, because it was a clean install of 9.10.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. System
 2. Preferences
 3. Keyboard
 4. Layouts (Tab)
 5. Options...
 6. Key(s) to change layout
 7. Change to the key combo you want :D

I otherwise have no idea why it would be in a different order. I can only suggest swapping key combinations and then back to Alt+Shift.

Comment: Definitely tried that. And it only happens on my netbook, not on my other laptops.
It's as if Shift+Alt is a different combination from Alt+Shift. Argh.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there are a number of long-standing bugs in handling switching between keyboard layout. I, for one, had problem with those in 9.10. For me they were fixed in 10.04. (FYI, [this](https://bugs.edge.launchpad.net/gdm/+bug/460328) is the bug that bit me.) Perhaps and upgrade to 10.04, which is a stable one after all, might fix this. Alternatively you might use a different key - I use the menu key, which has no use whatever for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it seems to be doing this whenever I set any <kbd>Shift</kbd> keys to toggle or cancel Caps Lock under the `Miscellaneous compatibility options` in the Keyboard Preferences (Keyboard Layout Options).